# create list of items grouped by an ID

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have the following 2 classes

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }     
}

public class School
{
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }          
    public IList<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

It might be strange to add the `SchoolId` inside the `Student` class but we do this for tracing.

In the database we have table `Students` that contains `StudentName` and `schoolId`

how can we rebuild list of `Schools` by selecting all from this tables

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Perhaps `Student` needs a property called School of `School`? `public School School {get;set;}`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Linq, but yes i can use it

Comment: Are you trying to create something like a dropdown list of `Schools` when you are creating a `Student`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward. Just use the [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) method in Linq.

```
var results = db.Students
    .GroupBy(s => s.SchoolId,
             (id, g) => new School() { SchoolId = id, Students = g.ToList() });
```

Or if you prefer the query syntax, use:

```
var results = 
    from s in db.Students
    group s by s.StudentId into g
    select new School()
    {
        SchoolId = g.Key,
        Students = g.ToList()
    };
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need the select clause in the first query, you could use the two-argument overload which does the value projection as well.